# Cygwin can't execute shell script

Tags: shell, windows-7, cygwin, cygpath

I am trying to execute a `.sh` file with Cygwin on Windows 7, and I'm getting an error `cannot execute binary file`.

Here is what I wrote in the Cygwin command prompt window:

```
$ bash cygpath --unix C:\Users\\MyName\\Documents\\MyProject\\dygraphsMaster\\generate-combined.sh
```

This was the result:

```
/usr/bin/cygpath: /usr/bin/cygpath: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: What are the permissions of your file? The first 3 letters should be rwx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your Windows path with double quotes (`"`) and your entire `cygpath` command with backticks (`` ` ``).

My example:

```
> pwd
/cygdrive/c/TestFolder/ScriptInsideHere

> ls -al
total 1
drwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  0 Aug 25 13:08 .
drwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  0 Aug 25 13:13 ..
-rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 29 Aug 25 13:08 hello_world.sh

> cat hello_world.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
```

Running the above:

```
> bash `cygpath --unix "C:\TestFolder\ScriptInsideHere\hello_world.sh"`
Hello World
```